# How to find out the variable type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I'm new to JavaScript and is writing a simple website using Netbeans. Since JavaScript is dynamically typed language, I was wondering how can I find out the type of a variable in situations where I am unsure of.

For example, how can I find out the variable type of `emailAddress` or `domainPart` in the code below?

```
function getEmailAndDomainParts(){
                var emailAddress = document.getElementById("EmailAddress").value;
                var emailPart = emailAddress.substring(0, emailAddress.indexOf("@"));
                var domainPart = emailAddress.substring(emailAddress.indexOf("@") + 1);

                document.getElementById("Email").value = emailPart;
                document.getElementById("Domain").value = domainPart;
            }
```

Comment: You can't find out the type of a *variable* because they don't have a type, but you can find out the type of the *value* in the variable using the `typeof` operator. Having said that, **all of your values are strings.** If `emailAddress` didn't contain a string you couldn't use `.substring()` on it, and `.substring()` will always return a string.

Comment: Did you try using typeof keyword? Something like:

    typeof emailAddress

Comment: Please allows look around first, this question been answered many many times before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// test data
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

// the usual typeof isn't very useful
alert(typeof myArray);

// this instance of method tests the array
// to see if it is an instance of the 'Array'
// constructor, which it is!
alert(myArray instanceof Array)
```

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonpage/6ebzd/2/)

Comment: You can also use `Array.isArray(myArray)`

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. You wouldn't use `instanceof` to test for strings, numbers, and boolean values (and even if that worked you'd have to call it multiple times until you got a match).

Answer (score 1):

you can use typeof:
The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand

Comment: What do you mean by "unevaluated operand"?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you cannot check the type of your variable but you can check the type of your variable's value using `typeof()`:

```
x = "hello";
y = 123;
z = true;
console.log(typeof(x)); //Will return "string"
console.log(typeof(y)); //Will return "number"
console.log(typeof(z)); //Will return "boolean"
```

Comment: Note that `typeof` is an operator, not a function. (The parentheses don't hurt, but they're not needed.)